# Undocumented Backslash-LessThan operator in strings?

Tags: syntax, cells, display, boxes, input-forms

I'm aware of the backslash operators in strings, as in [this SE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55982/backslash-commands-in-strings), but I ran across a new one.  I opened a new `Styled Notebook ...` in the front-end GUI, chose `Standard Report`, saved the notebook, then opened it in Emacs. I saw the following cell:

```
Cell["\<\
Enter text here. Enter TraditionalForm input for evaluation in a separate \
cell below:\
\>", "Text"],
```

and didn't recognize the `\<` and `\>` operators.  I experimented with them in another notebook, but couldn't see any difference:

[image]

Anyone happen to know what they're for?  Why they're there?  What they're supposed or not supposed to do?  Use cases for my own (automatically created) notebooks?

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105018/5467)