# What are the special characters `\!`, `\@`, etc.?

Tags: character-encoding

Character codes 63425 through 63436 (within the WL private use range) can be typed with backslash escape sequences. Despite displaying like digraphs they are single characters:

```
{"\!", "\@", "\%", "\^", "\&", "\*", "\(", "\+", "\/"}
{ToCharacterCode@#, StringLength@#}& /@ %

(* {"\!", "\@", "\%", "\^", "\&", "\*", "\(", "\+", "\/"}
{{{63425}, 1}, {{63426}, 1}, {{63429}, 1}, {{63430}, 1}, {{63431}, 1}, {{63432}, 1}, {{63433}, 1}, {{63435}, 1}, {{63436}, 1}} *)
```

These characters are not listed in the [Listing of Named Characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html). Calling `CharacterName` just returns `Missing[Notavailable]`. What are they used for?

Comment: They are documented in tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes. Closely related: [55982](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55982/5478)